# Sum of independent Geometric and NegBin random variables

Tags: probability-theory

Let $Y\sim \operatorname{Geom}(p)$ and $X\sim \operatorname{Negbin}(k,p)$ be independent. I’m trying to find the distribution of $X+Y$. What I have thus far is:
$$P(X+Y=m)=\sum_{i=1}^{m-k} P(X=m-i)\space P(Y=i)$$
$$=\frac{p^{k+1}(1-p)^{m-k}}{1-p} \space \sum_{i=1}^{m-k} \binom{m-i-1}{k-1}$$

From here, I’m not sure how to simplify the summation above. I tried expanding it, and it does not seem to be complicated, as it’s simply the sum of the binomial coefficients $\binom{m}{k-1}+\cdots+\binom{k-1}{k-1}$.
Any advice to simplify this summation? Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Geometric distribution" can be construed either as a distribution supported on the set $\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ or as a distribution supported on the set $\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\},$ and "negative binomial distribution" can mean either a distribution supported on $\{k,k+1,k+2,\ldots\}$ or one supported on $\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}.$ Which convention are you following here? $\qquad$

Comment: ok, It appears that you are following the $\{k,k+1,k+2,\ldots\}$ convention. The result should be negative binomial supported on the set $\{k+1,k+2,k+3,\ldots\}.$ Maybe I'll add details below at some point.

Comment: I follow the convention of support on set ${k,k+1,...}$. That’s why the limits of the summation end at $m-k$.

Comment: Ok, that does make some intuitive sense to me. What about my calculations above?  Do you have any advice to simplify the summation? Thanks for your comments already! @MichaelHardy

Comment: Note the function of $p$ that you get is $p^{k+1} (1-p)^{m - (k+1)},$ and that is the same as what you get in the probability mass function of $X$ except that you have $k+1$ where you had $k.$ Thus it remains only to deal with the identity on binomial coefficients. $\qquad$

Comment: So what you need to show is $$ \binom{m-1} k = \binom m {k-1} + \cdots + \binom {k-1}{k-1}. $$

Comment: What if we take $m=k+1$. This gives $\binom{m-1}{k}=1$ in the RHS. But the LHS is not necessarily 1. Isn’t this a contradiction to the equality you wrote, @MichaelHardy?

Comment: . . . . . I'll work out the details and come back later....

Comment: @MichaelHardy. I believe the sum you wrote above should start at $\binom{m-2}{k-1}...\binom{k-1}{k-1}$. I wrote an answer below, please let me know, if you can, if there are any issues with it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Pascal's rule: $\binom{n}{k-1}+\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n+1}{k}.$ Thus:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{m-k} \binom{m-i-1}{k-1}=\sum_{i=1}^{m-k} \binom{m-i}{k}-\binom{m-i-1}{k}=\binom {m-1}{k}$$

Since $\binom{n}{k}=0 \ \ \text{if} \ \ k \gt n.$

$$\text{Thus},\  P(X+Y=m)=\frac{p^{k+1}(1-p)^{m-k}}{1-p}\binom {m-1}{k}={p^{k+1}(1-p)^{m-(k+1)}}\binom {m-1}{k}$$
Thus,  $X+Y\sim \operatorname{Negbin}(k+1,p)$, as proposed in the comments.